# Making text clickable in Chrome, Firefox, Safari

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made this website www(.)ionisedmesh(.)com and a latest news box on the top but the problem is that while the blog posts headings are clickable in Internet Explorer, they cannot be clicked while using Firefox or Chrome, I havent tested with Safari but I am sure it wont work on it too if it doesnt work on Chrome. Here's my code, any suggestion?

```
<div id="freshlyWrapper">
<div id="freshlyposts">
<?php
$freshlyIonised = new WP_Query();
$freshlyIonised->query('category_name=FreshlyIonised&showposts=6');
while($freshlyIonised->have_posts()):
$freshlyIonised->the_post();    
$title = get_the_title();
if (strlen($title) > 46)
$title = substr( $title, 0 , 46 ) . "..."; // Limits title to 20 characters.
?>  
<div class="freshlyionisedbox"><h3><a style='text-decoration: underline; color: #000;' href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $title; ?>
</a></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you mean the contents of the h3? Please also include an example output.

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your HTML. I've just checked your page using Safari's Web Inspector (it's like Firebug) and it seems your Google Ads DIV and your Facebook DIV are covering up the div with your headlines. I removed those two and your headlines are clickable. I think you need to change how they're positioned, perhaps a `float:right`?

Comment: Disabling all styles also renders your headlines clickable, so it's definitely something to do with those following DIVs covering your headlines DIV. I usually add STYLE attributes with background colours to DIVs if I'm not sure what they're doing, that way you can see which DIV is really on top!

Comment: sorry for being a noob, but i dont get what you guys are talking about. Can you provide me with some specific code that i should be using?

Comment: You have two DIVs with inline styles, which have ```position:relative``` set, it's this which is causing the problem as they're then going over the top of your headlines DIV. If you change these to ```position:static``` then the page doesn't look as good, but the headlines work. To get it looking right again, I think you'll need to add the styles to the contents of these DIVs instead of the DIVs themselves. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: I used float:right for the latest news but the links are still not clickable

Comment: the facebook like box isnt interfering with the div containing the latest news but it is only the Ad one. How can I modify the ad CSS to display it properly. If I limit the width of the whole sidebar, should that help? If yes, can you guide me on how to do that?

Comment: You probably need to rethink your HTML layout, as the ad and Facebook DIVs are below your headlines DIV. You should think of it a bit like an HTML table (kind of) so you'd have ```<div id="top_bar">Site logo and search</div> <div id="headlines">Your headlines</div> <div id="main_stuff"> <div id="right_column" style="float:right"><div id="advert>ad code here</div><div id="facebook">FB code here</div></div> <div id="main_page_content">main content... etc. etc.```